# Recycler View repeats, how to view it once

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

The highlighted text get displayed with Case 0/Case 1/Case 2. As I said it repeats after the integer repeats.

My plan is that I only display the first 3 users as place numbers 1,2,3 (gold, silver, bronze).
So I don't want that this pattern repeats again, like in my case.

In my android app I use a ViewHolder and a RecyclerView. It looks like in the picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA0KJ.jpg) below:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA0KJ.jpg)

```
public class HighscoreAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HighscoreAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<User> userList;
private Context context;

public HighscoreAdapter(Context context,List<User> userList) {
    this.userList = userList;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public HighscoreAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_high_score_list,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HighscoreAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String userNickText = userList.get(position).getUserName();
    String userLetterText = context.getString(R.string.correct_letter_count)+ " " + userList.get(position).getUserLetterCount();
    String userWPMText = context.getString(R.string.WPM) + " " + userList.get(position).getUserScore();
    holder.textViewUserNick.setText(userNickText);
    holder.textViewUserScore.setText(userLetterText);
    holder.textViewUserLetter.setText(userWPMText);
```

I am sure the problem is that the position is counted as an integer, which means it counts 0-9.
So after 10 it starts again at 0.

```
        switch (position){
        case 0:
            holder.imgUserScore.setImageResource(R.drawable.gold);
            holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fffca2"));
            break;
        case 1:
            holder.imgUserScore.setImageResource(R.drawable.silber);
            holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#dbdbdb"));
            break;
        case 2:
            holder.imgUserScore.setImageResource(R.drawable.bronze);
            holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffd2a1"));
            break;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Don't use position to manipulate the list data. Use something related to data itself. Like if User object has a flag denoting whether it is gold / silver / bronze you can use it to show the badges instead of position.

Comment: Can you give me a bit more details how you thought about that? But thanks for your answer already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to set up a flag field in the model class that you pass to the `recyclerview adapter` like this

```
Class User{
   String name;
   int placeType; // This is the flag we need to set up.
   
   User(String name, int placeType)
   // setters and getters for the fields name and placeType
}
```

And inside the adapter, while binding the data to the view, you need to validate the flag for `placeType` displaying the badges/setting color like below.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HighscoreAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String name = userList.get(position).getName();
    int placeType=  userList.get(position).getPlaceType();
    // other snippets
    //Set the color like below based on place type.

    if(placeType== 1){ // First place
       itemview.setBackgroundColor("GOLD COLOR")
    }else if(placeType== 2){ // Second place
       itemview.setBackgroundColor("SILVER COLOR")
    }else if(placeType== 3){ // Third place
       itemview.setBackgroundColor("BRASS COLOR")
    }else{
       itemview.setBackgroundColor("NO COLOR") // For other cases 
    }
```

However this is not the entire solution but have provided you with some logic / input to your problem.